# how to fetch a method from a json file and display it on a Label or webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

i am new to iphone development.i am doing one project where i am connecting to a webservice and getting a json responsestring and parsing json getting the requried output..

when i click a button the required data is getting displayed on label..

//REQUIREMENT

what is  my requirement is i shd have a TextField,button and a label or webview in UI

when i enter a string in textfield it should search from the jsonfile and should display the result of particular method on label or webview.

so how to implement this plz suggest changes need to be done in the code.

//source code

**.h file**

```
      IBOutlet UILabel* label;

        NSMutableData *dataWebService; 
    }

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *dataWebService;

-(IBAction)loadData;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)loadData

{

    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]]retain];  

      [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}






-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{ 

     [connection release]; 

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.dataWebService = nil;

    NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"];

    [responseString release];    

    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

    //fetch the data
    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];

    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];

    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

    //set the text to the label
    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ \n \n country:  %@ \n \n amount: $%.2f", name,country,outstandingAmount];


}
```

Comment: So you want to search `latestLoans` and show the results in a label or a webview?

Comment: yup i wan to have a textfield where i will be entering a string like example "Latestloans" and press button tat shd be searched from a json file and shd display on webview or label..

Comment: @deepak  yup i wan to have a textfield where i will be entering a string like example "Latestloans" and press button tat shd be searched from a json file and shd display on webview or label

Comment: This is what I understand of your problem. You get a response from the web which is a list of loans with particular details i.e. rows with columns stored in an array of `NSDictionary`s. You want to search this list based on a query provided by the user. Now are we searching a particular column or all columns? And then are we to retrieve a particular column corresponding in the row that matches our criteria or the entire row?

Comment: @Deepak ya response from the web is json file...u can see the above url in the code...but it doesnt matter particular row or coloumn...when u type string in textfield it shd search and display first 4 or 5 resuls which matches with the string...no issues with row or column..can tel me both the ways